# How to build the shiny-server from source on Debian?

Tags: r, github, debian, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to launch an shiny server on company's Debian machine. Based on the wiki: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/wiki/Building-Shiny-Server-from-Source, I choose to "build the server from source" since Debian is not a supported distribution.

I was following the instruction step by step. However, I had an error when I tried to run:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DPYTHON="$PYTHON" ../

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

CMake Error at external/pandoc/CMakeLists.txt:14 (file):
   file DOWNLOAD HASH mismatch

    for file: [/home/mli/shiny_server/shiny-server/tmp/external/pandoc/pandoc-1.12.3.zip]
        expected hash: [1541304bf51d86e361b7d930f899ac1c]
        actual hash: [d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e]
        status: [7;"Couldn't connect to server"]
```

The detail of the error listed as:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/mli/shiny_server/shiny-server/tmp/external/pandoc/pandoc-1.12.3.zip’: File exists
       End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
       a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
       latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
       the last disk(s) of this archive.
```

I have been searching a solution for a couple days but nothing is really working for me yet. It would be very nice if anyone could help me on this..

As an alternative, I have also downloaded the "shiny-server-1.3.0.403-amd64.deb" and installed it with "$ sudo gdebi". It successfully installed with a small error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 

Shiny Server
Shiny Server is a server program from RStudio, Inc. that makes Shiny applications available over the web. Shiny is a web application framework for the  R statistical computation language.
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
Selecting previously unselected package shiny-server.
(Reading database ... 49759 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack shiny-server-1.3.0.403-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking shiny-server (1.3.0.403) ...
Setting up shiny-server (1.3.0.403) ...
User shiny already exists
grep: /etc/init/shiny-server.conf: No such file or directory
Adding LANG to /etc/init.d/shiny-server, setting to en_US.UTF-8
```

However, I can't initiate the server by:

```
$ sudo start shiny-server
```

Nothing happened after I ran the "start" command. Also, my Debian version is below:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.4 (jessie)
Release:    8.4
Codename:   jessie
```

Comment: Since the Ubuntu installer is a `deb` file, I would assume that it works on Debian?

Comment: @warmoverflow You mean directly install "shiny-server-1.3.0.403-amd64.deb" package with "sudo gdebi"? I did it in my first trial. However, though it successfully installed, I can't initiate shiny server by "$ sudo start shiny-server". Nothing happened. Then, on the other machine, I have tried access the sample shiny app via the url "[DNS]:3838/sample-apps/hello/". Again, there is nothing open on that port:8383..

Comment: What's the Debian version? It is possible that it uses systemd. See http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#stopping-and-starting for the correct command.

Comment: @warmoverflow My Debian version is "Debian GNU/Linux 8.4 (jessie)". I tried "$ sudo systemctl start shiny-server" but still nothing happened. Then I tried "$ sudo systemctl status shiny-server" and it returns status like "● shiny-server.service - LSB: shiny Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/shiny-server)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2016-05-02 10:50:15 PDT; 2 days ago" Does it mean shiny server is working on my Debian machine?

Comment: when I tried the url "[DNS]:3838" via browser on another machine. It still gives me "[DNS] refused to connect."

Comment: Based on this link http://citkts.com/index.php/2015/12/29/installing-r-r-studio-shiny-server-to-debian-8-server/ it should work (note only install openssl when you get a related error)

Comment: This is really encouraging!:) Thank you @warmoverflow ! I am trying to use his version of shiny-server.deb. Before that, I uninstalled my current shiny-server by "$ sudo apt-get --purge remove shiny-server". It successfully finished. However, I can still see the same "active" status of shiny-server by using "$ sudo systemctl status shiny-server". How can I uninstall it totally?

Comment: @warmoverflow It works!! Thank you so much! :P I just need the latest shiny-server.deb package.

Answer (score 0):

after gdebi install u can run /usr/bin/shiny-server to start the server